# Виртуализация с пиксельным скроллом

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, прокрутка, ui

Доброго времени суток! В моем `ListView` есть элементы, высота которых может быть довольно большой. Соответственно при логическом скролле (`ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"`) скролл прыгает с элемента на элемент, а полностью высокие элементы увидеть невозможно. Возникает вопрос: какой Control поддерживает виртуализацию с таким вот скроллом: `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`?

Comment: По теме: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3724593/276994

Comment: А вот тут, кажется, решение: http://classpattern.com/smooth-scrolling-with-virtualization-wpf-list.html